# How to make the posts of a content type horizontal scrollabel?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my teaser view of the content type (application_formulier) scrollabel on the x-axis instead of the y-axis. I made a view for this (view-view-s4p).

Using CSS I got the following:

```
.view-view-s4p{
margin-left:-50px;
max-width:920px;
min-width:920px;
height:260px;
overflow:auto;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
.view-view-s4p .view-content {
margin:0 -32767px 0 0;/* browser limit */
height:240px;
}
.view-view-s4p .view-row{
float:left;
}
```

I now have the scroll working but it go's way past the last post... Any idee on how to fix this.

Go to this link to see an image of my problem:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7sse3shk08ex9g6/problem.PNG

(btw: if i'm not allowed to change my question like this plz let me know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
.wrap {
    overflow:auto;
    width:600px;
    height:220px;
    padding:10px;
}
.inner {
    float:left;
    margin:0 -32767px 0 0;/* browser limit */
}
.inner div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 10px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="inner">
                <div>test</div>
                <div>test</div>
                <div>test</div>
                <div>test</div>
                <div>test</div>
                <div>test</div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Source](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?868236-Horizontal-Scrolling-Area&p=5154977#post5154977)

Comment: Hi thx for helping me, I tried what you said but it didn't work. Any other idees?

Comment: Hi again, I fixed it. You need to remove the float:left; form the first inner class. If you do that you can float the items over the x-axis. Perfectly like i needed it.     On more thing if you dont mind... Do you know of a way to stop the margin after the last post (inner div)? Because now  my scroll bar doesn't stop... (plz tell me if you don't understand my question...)

Comment: Hm, the example code I gave (if you paste it into a plank .html file and open it in your browser) works just fine, and only scrolls as far as the inner content goes. That's a good point to start from, and perhaps make changes as you go and keep testing. Otherwise, perhaps post an example of what you have now.

Comment: Hey ralph, i eddited my code to what i have now. The scroll works but it go's past the last post. Could you plz take a look at it again? (If i have some time ill put my project online so you can see it directly.)

Comment: Hey again, I tested my website on some other browsers and on Chrome it works without trouble. But on IE and Firefox it go's on like in the picture added above. Any idee how to overcome this browser problem?

Comment: We might need to see your actual example, as that's odd. We need to see what code you are actually using.

Comment: Hey ralph. I put my website online and you can go to the page in question using this link: http://wazaa-stucrew.rhcloud.com/S4P            The problem is still there that only on chrome it works correct...

Comment: Hm, you didn't actually follow the code above carefully. Don't pick and choose from it. You left out these critical bits: `.view-content {float: left;} .views-row {float: left;}`

Comment: Hey again, Eum like i said in one off the previous comments. If i put a '.float:left;' in the '.view-content' it wil only give me one post and you can scroll anymore... (You can test this your self if you use firebug)

Comment: So you aren't going to try adding what I just gave you? Float on both elements, as in the original code? I did test it ...

Comment: Hey ralph, I'm sorry if i made you misunderstand me. I did try to do what you said but then i get the following: https://www.dropbox.com/s/67t5agxym7oxiei/Example3.PNG    I don't know if what you mean is somthing differn't and I'm just overlooking it but could you take an other look plz?   (btw: the .view-row has a float left)

Comment: It's really simple. As I said, add this to your style sheet: `.view-content {float: left;} .views-row {float: left;}`. It can't be easier. Try it! Here's even a demo for you: http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-16589521/ Open it in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `white-space:nowrap;` property to your stylesheet is what you need:

```
.view-view-s4p{
  margin-left:-50px;
  width:auto;
  min-width:960px;
  max-height:253px;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9Usn/1/)

Comment: Hi thx for helping me, I tried what you said but it didn't work. Any other idees?